Why a single fixed gear opposite a freewheel gear on same axle
.I have a single speed bike with a single fixed gear on the opposite side of the same axle. What is the fixed gear used for?
+

You are aware that the wheel can just be “flipped“, making the fixed sprocket the one in use, right? I.e. you are not just asking why you have a seemingly superfluous sprocket on the left side?

Thank you all for the responses. I learned a lot. Your input is very valuable to me.

Flip-flop fixed/freewheel hubs in actual practice are primarily used for switching to the freewheel after one discovers they don't like riding fixed.
You can find reference to other nominal purposes, and if you look hard enough you can find cyclists using flip-flop hubs for those purposes. The major example is primarily running the bike fixed but having the option of flipping the wheel for hillier terrain. This side could be set up with the same gearing or a little bit lower, within what the chain length can be configured for.
Another theoretical example is someone who wants to be able to switch to fixed for when they get to the track.

I think it would be more honest to just say that you tried riding fixed, couldn't handle it and can't stand that others can.

@ojs I think the explanation makes sense as-is. A FF hub is mostly a hedge against not wanting to ride fixie.

It's been over a decade since I've thought about the practical nuances of riding to and then at a velodrome. But if you used the freewheel side to get there, you'd need brakes on the bikes. So once you're there, you probably aren't allowed to ride a bike with brakes on the 'drome, right?

@PaulH this is why brakes are typically bolted, not welded in place. If you want to go all in and use non drilled track fork, "keirin brakesets" are a thing: https://www.euroasiaimports.com/productcart/pc/Dia-Compe-Keirin-Front-Brakeset-p6563.htm
